# How to create add WinRT objects in C++/CX at runtime?

Tags: c++-cx

I want to create a WinRT object (say a textblock) in a function (say an event) and add it to a page (say a grid setting its row and column nos. all at runtime) in C++/CX. Is it possible?

Comment: i dont get why has this question led to reduce the reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call 'ref new' on the class as you would any other object, and add it to the 'Children' collection of the grid.

In order to set the grid row and column, you need to set the attached properties by calling SetRow/SetColumn on the grid.

This is all most easily accomplished by naming the grid in the xaml file (using the x:Name attribute) so that you can refer to it by name in code.  Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
auto textBlock = ref new TextBlock();
textBlock->Text = "this is my text";
myGrid->Children->Append(textBlock);
myGrid->SetRow(textBlock, 1);
myGrid->SetColumn(textBlock, 0);
```

Comment: and how to set is properties?
textBlock->VerticalAlignment=Center does not work.

Comment: In code, the VerticalAlignment property is of type Windows::UI::Xaml::VerticalAlignment.  So you need to set the property using an enumeration from that type.  C++ name hiding will also make this a problem because the page likely has its own member named VerticalAlignment, so you will need to qualify the typename.

`textBlock->VerticalAlignment = Windows::UI::Xaml::VerticalAlignment::Center;`

Comment: I am sorry am not eligible to vote in reputation else I would have definitely done that